# what happend when golang convert struct to interface{} ? what is the cost?

Tags: go, struct, interface

i'm confused about interface{} type,
how to build an interface{} object from Person struct?
if the struct is very big,  the conversion cost whether is expensive

```
type Person struct {  
  name string  
  age  int  
} 

func test(any interface{}) {  

} 

func main() {  
    p := Person{"test", 11}
    // how to build an interface{} object from person struct? 
    // what is the cost? the field need copy?
    test(p) 
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you do not understand `interface{}` do not use it.

Comment: in fact, i don't want to use, but many library function's iput parameter is interface{} type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interface{} is a type. It consists of two things : underlying type and underlying value. Size doesn't matter. Cost is that every time convert it or to it, you incur cost. One thing that size effect is value during copying from struct to interface underlying value. But this cost is similar to one you get when you assign to a struct or copy to a struct. The additional cost of interface isn't affected by size.

You don't need that function to convert, you can convert it like this:

```
func main() {
    p := Person{"test", 11}
    // how to build an interface{} object from person struct?
    // what is the cost? the field need copy?
    var v interface{}
    v = p    
}
```

Comment: when convert , it just assign the underlying pointer ? or need to make a new tmp object ,then copy value?

Comment: Nope. A copy of value in above sample.

Comment: Similarly when you convert it to value like k := v.(Person), it uses a  new value. But that's not the only cost then, type checking is one more cost.

Comment: sorry, v = p, if the assignment  follow the three step, first allocate a new object on heap, second copy p values to new object, third, assign the v pointer to new object, the asssignment cost is very expensive, if the p object size is big

Comment: Yes. But that cost will remain even if you assign to another struct var.  Or copy to another value. What's different from a struct to interface will be type checking cost and underlying type cost. Will modify my answer with this clarification.

Comment: i have long time c experience, if v =p need to copy value, i have to use pointer to avoid the copy process, i hope the v can just hold the pointer to p, then it don't need to copy underlying value

Comment: @DongLiu You can avoid that too in interface using pointer. Check here https://play.golang.org/p/Or62SdNG-S

Comment: But there's one more additional cost as I said, cost of underlying type and during conversion, type checking.

Comment: i suspect ,  v = p doesn't copy value,  the copy process happens when execute following code  p1, ok := v.(Person)

Comment: i can't access the url： play.golang.org/p/8BbTsIXZOt  , the reply is forbbiden

Comment: yes, play.golang.org is normal, https://play.golang.org/p/8BbTsIXZOt can't access, you can send the content via email liudong9183@163.com

Comment: I created both here:  https://gist.github.com/khrm/26e4e71ec08fac6af303b0a632a52197

Comment: how to prove your idea?

Comment: In that you will see that changing the value in struct isn't changing the value in interface

Comment: i read the code, maybe you 're right..i need to think ..i use json.Marshal(v interface{}) function,  the object is very large, the cost of copy is hard to accept..

Comment: Don't use interface to marshal if you know the struct. Use struct.

Comment: json.Marshal is offical library function, it use interface{} as input parameter type

Comment: Welcome. Accept if it was useful. I would recommend ffjson for marshalling if performance is a factor.